# Как не показывать pop-up если поле не заполнено

Tags: html

подскажите пожалуйста как не показывать поп если поле не заполнено

```
<button onclick="alert('Click');" type="submit" id="pixel-form-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >Click!
                                        </button>
```

pop-up элементарный

Comment: Если не заполнено какое поле?

Comment: Есть поле Name, если поле заполнено необходимо выводить pop-up, если поле не заполнено, то "заполните пожалуйста поле", извиняюсь за некорректный вопрос я тут впервые)

Comment: А зачем его показывать, если поле не заполнено?

Comment: когда поля будут заполнены по нажатию кнопки "отправить" будет выплывать поп ап "сообщение отправлено" если поля не заполнены надо казать какое поле не заполнено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если фраза "Заполните пожалуйста поле" тоже должно быть в popup:

```js
    function zhmyak() {
        let Name = document.getElementById('Name');
        if (Name.value){
            alert('Click')
        } else {
            alert("заполните пожалуйста поле");
        }
    }
```

```html
<input id="Name">

<button onclick="zhmyak();" type="submit" id="pixel-form-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >Click!
```

Если поле "Заполните пожалуйста поле" должно быть на странице:

```js
    function zhmyak() {
        let Name = document.getElementById('Name');
        let fill = document.getElementById('fill');
        if (Name.value){
            fill.innerText = "";
            alert('Click');
        } else {
            fill.innerText = "Заполните пожалуйста поле";
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="fill"></div>
<input id="Name">

<button onclick="zhmyak();" type="submit" id="pixel-form-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" >Click!
```